# The printer is not responding on Kubuntu 18.04 with Canon MF232w

Tags: networking, drivers, kubuntu, printing, canon

I had Canon ImageCLASS MF232w network printer working on Ubuntu 18.04.4 with Canon drivers. I made a fresh installation of Kubuntu 18.04.5, Canon linux-UFRII-drv-v520-uken driver and registered the printer. Printing a test page from `Printers - System Settings Module` ends with `The printer is not responding` status and nothing is being printed. I went step by step through https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems and everything seems to be normal to my eye. I rebooted the PC and power cycled the printer to no avail.

In `Configure Printer -> Modify Printer -> Connection` dialog, I tried IP address or name of my PC: `socket://192.168.0.8`, `socket://192.168.0.8/24` and `socket://extra` and no cigar. When I change it to `lpd://extra` printing the test page hangs up in `The printer is in use` state.

I would be grateful for any clues.

**EDIT**

The printer is definitely alive and available on the network. It must be some configuration issue:

```
paul@extra:~$ snmpwalk -Cc -v 1 -c public 192.168.0.11 | tee snmpwalk.log
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 = STRING: "Canon MF230 Series /P"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0 = OID: iso.3.6.1.4.1.1602.4.7
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 = Timeticks: (30032) 0:05:00.32
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0 = ""
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 = STRING: "MF230 Series"
.....
```

**EDIT 2**

I tried to make it work on fresh installs of Kubuntu 18.04.5 and 20.04.1 with the same result. Finally, I installed Ubuntu 18.04.5 again, unplugged the printer from the network and connected it via USB. I've got the printer working, but not the scanner.